# How to store ndarray in csv format each array in a different colums using pandas?

Tags: python-3.x

I have been looking this up but all the answers I find is for 2D array. Lets say I have the following not working code

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 

my_list=[]
def run:
    for i in range(500): 
       a = raw_data_get() # this brings in raw data as tuples such as (array([1.34, 1.3, 9.1]), array([3.2, 8.1, 7.3]))
       my_list.append(a)
    for i in range(len(my_list)):
       df = pd.DataFrame(my_list[i]).T
    df.to_csv('my_signals.csv', index=False)
```

and I want to store each array in a separate column in csv format. The output should look like this:

```
col1  col2  col3  col4
1       2     3     4
2       2     3     4
3       2     3     4
4       2     3     4
```

How can I solve the same problem if I have 500 arrays not just four? so I can have several columns in csv?

```
col1  col2  col3  col4  .... etc
1       2     3     4
2       2     3     4
3       2     3     4
4       2     3     4
```

I am using python3.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data in variable a is nested in one list too many. Try `a = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4]]` and put it in a dataframe like `df = pd.DataFrame(a)` and then convert it to .csv like `df.to_csv(df)`

Or try:

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 

my_list=[]
for i in range(500):
       a = raw_data_get() # this brings in raw data as tuples such as (array([1.34, 1.3, 9.1]), array([3.2, 8.1, 7.3]))
       my_list.append(a)
flat_list = [item for sublist in my_list for item in sublist]
df = pd.DataFrame(flat_list).T
df.to_csv('my_signals.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: You can also access the list within a by referring to a[0]

Comment: my array has three quotes and the answer you have has only two [[ ]]. The second answer is not very clear to me. Can you please show me how to fix my code? What line I need to change?

Comment: You can only put an array of arrays in a dataframe when it has one [ ] around the arrays. Delete all the code in the question and take the code from my answer.

Comment: all my real data come in as array([[[1, 2, 3, 4],
        [2, 2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3, 3],
        [4, 4, 4, 4]]])
so they all have three quotes. I get below error:    raise ValueError(f"Must pass 2-d input. shape={values.shape}")
ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(1, 4, 4)

Comment: Let me rephrase my answer

Comment: If my real data come in as an array of arrays with two quotes my problems would of been solved. But the problem is my real data come in with three quotes [[[ ]]] and I don't know how to convert them into two [[ ]] array so the code will work.

Comment: Check out the bottom part of my answer.

Comment: I tried it it puts all the data in two cloums. The problem is my data. Here is the real data I have been talking about [[[12.99 23.445 77.43] [8.48 8.3 -7.5]] [[1.3  1.5  9.8] [8.2 -8.7 -7.1]]]. Any idea of how should I approach this?

Comment: In what format/file is that data? Are you reading it in your python script?

Comment: Yes I am reading it with my python script. The data comes in as <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: So let say a = [[[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4]]] and a is <class 'numpy.ndarray'>. Try to assign a[0] to b and put b in a dataframe, like in my answer code.

Comment: I already assigned a[0] to b and placed b in the data frame as you first provided that answer but it didn't help. The problem is the type of the data I am working with. as I said the real data come in as  [[[12.99 23.445 77.43] [8.48 8.3 -7.5]] [[1.3 1.5 9.8] [8.2 -8.7 -7.1]]]. IDK how to treat the real data to process it.

Comment: Please note there is no comma separator in the real data. If you plug the real data into the code above you will get the same error I am getting.

Comment: But [[[12.99 23.445 77.43] [8.48 8.3 -7.5]] [[1.3 1.5 9.8] [8.2 -8.7 -7.1]]] is invalid syntax. Do you read it as a string? What is the type of the variable where you store [[[12.99 23.445 77.43] [8.48 8.3 -7.5]] [[1.3 1.5 9.8] [8.2 -8.7 -7.1]]]?

Comment: The data first come in as tuples. I append each tuple to a list. Then I convert the list to an array using np.asarry which gives me the data you are seeing above.

Comment: The raw data come in as (array([1.34 , 1.3,  9.1]), array([3.2, 8.1, 7.3]))  which is <class 'tuple'>

Comment: If you put that tuple in a dataframe directly it should work.

Comment: I tried to put it into a dataframe directly but all goes into two rows as the previous one.

Comment: You can also transpose the dataframe like df.T if that is what you’re looking for

Comment: Ok that did put the data of one sets of tuples into csv column1 and column2. But I need to run in loop 500+ times to capture every single run. How can I do that?

Comment: You append all the arrays to a list in a loop and then put the collection of arrays in a dataframe and transpose the dataframe

Comment: for i in range (500): a = mytuple_capture.get() #This captures the tuple value df=pd.DataFrame(a).T     #this code writes to only two columns and ignores the rest of the run. How can I fix that?

Comment: I did couple things both failed. first I tried to iterate over a list and append one array at the time   for i in range(len(my_list)):
        df = pd.DataFrame(my_list[i]).T  this didn't work and gave me only two columns. then I tried to do  df = pd.DataFrame(my_list).T also didn't work. it puts only the last capture in two raws.

Comment: Could you put the complete code in your question?

Comment: I did put the actual code in the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231762/discussion-between-dsteman-and-user8607309).